# ionic 4 slow compile time

Tags: ionic-framework, compilation, ionic4

My new Ionic projects take more than 100000ms everytime it compiles. tried it with multiple new project, all of them are extremely slow.

```
[ng] i ｢wdm｣: Compiling...
[ng] Date: 2018-10-09T13:28:58.064Z - Hash: 65e0e0d39e445c0b5c3b - Time: 106610ms
[ng] 173 unchanged chunks
[ng] chunk {home-home-module} home-home-module.js, home-home-module.js.map (home-home-module) 6.36 kB  [rendered]
[ng] i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Ionic version: 4.1.1

Node Version: 8.11.1

Comment: Upgrade your node and npm to the latest version, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to upgrade to the current Node version (not the LTS version). That kind of solved the issue.